# Launch images for iOS versions below v.8

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been reading the apple docs and it says that iOS 8+ uses the .xib file for the launch screen setup. For older versions you need to use launch images. So do I need to add this to my image assets? I'm not sure what I need to name them. Do I have to have a separate asset for each iPhone screen size 4 and 5? I presume I don't need to do one for the iPhone 6 an 6+ as it will be using iOS 8 so will use the xib...Any tips would be really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new launch image set:

[image]

After selecting the image set, you can specify what type of images you want:

[image]

The image set will update automatically based on what you select.

Comment: This is good thanks, says the resolutions I need also. If you have a LaunchImage setup and the LaunchScreen.xib setup which one will it choose on an iOS 8 device?

Comment: Um... try and see? Though as I can see in my small test, it prioritises the xib.

Answer (score 0):

Form iOS 8 it is possible to use a .xib for the launch screen, but it is not mandatory. You can still use the image assets catalog in iOS 8.

You will need to a launch screen for each device image size your app is supporting. And support 3.5" and 4" is mandatory.